# Adding a webapp "alias" to Tomcat 7 on Linux

Tags: linux, tomcat, tomcat7

I have a Tomcat 7 running on CentOS.

Given is a configuration where I have my webapp "foo" placed in webapps/foo.war. I can access it without any problems using http://host.name/foo.

Now I want to get access to the same webapp using a 2nd URL - "http://host.name/bar".

Setting up a webserver in front of my Tomcat is not an option so I need something like mod_rewrite for Tomcat.

What I have tried so far is to setup another context like this:

```
<Context path="/bar" docBase="foo"/>
```

At first it seems to work, but at the second look it shows that this isn't actually an "alias" - it is a second instance from my webapp which really is not a valid option for me.

So... does anybody know how to get some kind of aliasing or URL rewriting for Tomcat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something similar to `mod_rewrite` for servlet containers called [URL Rewrite](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/). Taken from [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563799/how-to-rewrite-url-in-tomcat-6).

Comment: Same problem. Using this config I have two seperate instances from my webapp (and so I have 2 different instance from my cache...)

Comment: @pascal-schmiel I've updated my answer.

Comment: I've put all the stuff in my ROOT webapp, added my rewrite rule and it's working perfect - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In your special case, what about setting a symlink in your webapps directory?

Asume your directory looks like this:

```
ls webapps/
foo  foo.war
```

Just add a symlink to foo with the name bar:

```
ln -s foo bar
```

Getting this:

```
ls webapps/
foo  bar  foo.war
```

Comment: looks like a great idea.
sad news: with a symlink in my webapps directory I get a second webapp instance too ("bar" directory in work/Catalina/localhost/)

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to find (a few exist) or write a small Java web app that reverse proxies from one URL pattern to another. See https://github.com/ahabra/reverse-proxy.